# Obtaining Required columns in HTML output in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

I obtained the BIOS data and saved it in HTML file but i don't want all the data to be in the file and i also need to format it so that it could suite my requirement.

Code:

```
$bios = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_BIOS" -namespace "root\CIMV2"
[string]$body = $bios | ConvertTo-Html -As List| Out-File c:/d/d/Test.htm
```

Comment: Data can be filtered using the `Select-Object` cmdlet. As for the format suiting your requirements: what *are* your requirements?

Comment: I need it to be in a tabular column

Comment: What information are you wanting? Like the Manufacturer, name, etc. ?

Comment: I need the following data
1) Syatem Name
2)Manufacturer 
3) Available Space
4) SerialNumber 
5)Version
save the data in html file in tabular column how can i get those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on the discussion in the comments, I think you are looking for something like this:

```
function GetCompInfoWork 
{
   param (
     [string]$computername,[string]$logfile
     )
    $os = Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $computername
    $bios = Get-WmiObject win32_bios -ComputerName $computername
    $disk = Get-WmiObject win32_logicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID= 'C:'" `
    -computername $computername

    $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject

    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty `
        -Name ComputerName -Value ($os.csname)
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty `
        -Name Manufacturer -Value ($bios.manufacturer)
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty `
        -Name SysDriveFree -Value ($disk.freespace / 1GB -as [int])
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty `
        -Name SerialNumber -Value ($bios.serialnumber)
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty `
        -Name Version -Value ($bios.version)            
    Write-Output $obj
}
function Get-CompInfo 
{
  param ([string[]]$computername,[string]$logfile )

  BEGIN
  {
    $usedParamater = $False
    if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('computername')) {
        $usedParamater = $True
        }
  }
  PROCESS {
    if ($usedParamater) 
    {
        foreach ($computer in $computername)
        {
            Getcompinfowork -computername $computer `
            -logfile $logfile
        }
    }          
    else 
    {
        Getcompinfowork -computername $_ `
        -logfile $logfile
    }

  }
  END {}
}

Get-CompInfo -computername localhost | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File C:\Output.html
```

Comment: FreeSpace    : 16455
Size         : 25454 this is shown by my $disk
but my output file shows following data

SysDriveSpace SysDriveFree
0             158   why is this discrepancy

Comment: Thank you sooo much for your help it was quite handy :)

Comment: @user2540455 Glad I can help.  I use something similar to this script at work.  I just modified it to meet your criteria.  Did you figure out the disk space discrepancy?

Comment: I am not having any problems with it.  Try just running the command:  Gwmi win32_logicaldisk -filer "deviceID= 'C:'" | select {$_.freespace / 1GB -as [int]}

Comment: i thought i can make 2 answers as correct just now came to know that i can do only for one :)
and one more doubt how do we find the max ram a computer can be fitted with

Comment: hmm..  thats a tricky one.  You can use the win32_physicalmemory class, but it lists the capacity of each DIMM slot.  I suppose it could be looped through to add up the capacity of each dimm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$freeSpace = (gwmi Win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DeviceID = 'C:'").FreeSpace

gwmi Win32_BIOS `
  | select PSComputerName,Manufacturer,SerialNumber,Version,
      @{n="AvailableSpace";e={[int]($freeSpace / 1MB)}} `
  | ConvertTo-Html `
  | Out-File "C:/d/d/Test.htm"
```

Comment: i was referring to the harddisk space available i need all these to be in the html file

Comment: $disk = ([wmi]"\root\cimv2:Win32_logicalDisk.DeviceID='c:'")
"Amount of Free Space C: has {0:#.0} GB Total" -f ($disk.FreeSpace/1GB)| write-output
i need this data also to be included in the html file along with the other data

Comment: Added free disk space calculation.

Comment: works great just out of curiosity if there are many drives then how do we go by ? as in this case we are confining it to just C drive. I truly appreciate your effort thank you soo much for your support.

Comment: You really shouldn't ask someone for more help when you just unaccepted their answer.

Comment: i never said i did not accept the answer :( just out of curiosity i asked it